# Truncated QR decomposition update (column deletion):

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we begin with a matrix V and create a new matrix L by appending A*V and V as columns, i.e., $$L = [AV, V],$$where A has dimensions **(N,N)**, and V of dim **(N,r)**.

Afterward, we perform a truncated QR decomposition on L, resulting in Q with dimensions **(N, 2r)** and R with dimensions **(2r, 2*r)**, where r is the rank of V. We concatenate two such matrices.

Now, the objective is to compute the modified QR decomposition of subsets of the first column of V, such as $$L_1 = [A*V(:,1), V(:,1)],$$ $$L_2 = [A*V(:,1:2), V(:,1:2)],$$ and so on, until a certain condition is met.

My question is: What is the most efficient method to compute the modified QR decomposition of L_1, L_2, and so forth? MATLAB provides an algorithm called "qrdelete" that updates the R matrix by removing the corresponding columns to be deleted and applies Givens rotations to eliminate subdiagonal elements one at a time. Is there a more optimized approach for this task?

I appreciate your assistance in advance.